# What are the color bars on the left of sublime screen

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm editing a matlab file on Sublime 3.2 and noticed that color indicator on the left, which seems related to some newline formatting.

Is there any reference about the proper syntax which this indicator is based on?

[image: sublime left indicator]

Comment: The indicators in the margins tell you about changes in the file; lines can be marked as modified, added or deleted. Deletions show as arrows, the other two are lines as above; the color is determined by your color scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime recently added Git, this might be git changes indicator. [Check this link](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/git_integration.html#status_bar) for more details, but it will work for files which are not tracked by git.

Comment: Specifically, that's Incremental Diff, not Git Integration (i.e. it works even in files not tracked by git).